# Using auto in lambda function declaration

Tags: c++, exception, lambda, std-function

When can `auto` be used as the type specifier of a variable initialized with a lambda function? I'm try to use `auto` in the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A
{
    const std::function <void ()>* m_Lambda = nullptr;

public:
    A(const std::function <void ()>& lambda): m_Lambda (&lambda) {}

    void ExecuteLambda()
    {
        (*m_Lambda)();
    }
};

void main()
{
    int i1 = 1;
    int i2 = 2;
    
    const auto lambda = [&]()
    {
        std::cout << "i1 == " << i1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "i2 == " << i2 << std::endl;
    };

    A a(lambda);
    a.ExecuteLambda();
}
```

I'm using *Visual Studio Community 2019* and when I start executing `a.ExecuteLambda()`, the program stops with the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76D9B5B2 in lambda.exe: 
Microsoft C ++ exception: std :: bad_function_call at memory location 0x00B5F434.
```

If I change the line `const auto lambda = [&]()` to `const std::function <void ()> lambda = [&]()`, it works perfectly. Why is it not allowed to use `auto`? Can something be changed to allow it to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lambda expression does not result in a `std::function`.  Instead, it creates an unnamed unique class type and that has an overload for `operator()`.  When you pass your lambda to `A`'s constructor, it creates a temporary `std::function` object, and you store a pointer to that temporary object.  When `A`'s constructor ends, that temporary object is destroyed, leaving you with a dangling pointer.

To fix this, just get rid of using pointers.  That would look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A
{
    std::function <void ()> m_Lambda;
public:
    A(const std::function <void ()> lambda): m_Lambda (lambda) {}

    void ExecuteLambda()
    {
        m_Lambda();
    }
};

void main()
{
    int i1 = 1;
    int i2 = 2;
    
    const auto lambda = [&]()
    {
        std::cout << "i1 == " << i1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "i2 == " << i2 << std::endl;
    };

    A a(lambda);
    a.ExecuteLambda();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are storing a **dangling `std::function` pointer** in your `A` object.

A lambda expression is not a `std::function` object, it is a compiler-defined type that is *assignable* to a `std::function` object.

When you declare `lambda` using `auto`, it gets a unique type.  To bind this `lambda` to the `A` constructor's parameter, a *temporary* `std::function` object is created, which you are storing a pointer to. But then, that *temporary* gets destroyed when the constructor exits, which is why you get the exception when you try to execute the `std::function`.

When you change the declaration of `lambda` to `std::function` instead, the `A` constructor's parameter is able to bind to that object as-is, and no temporary is created.

You should be passing and storing `std::function` objects by value instead of by pointer, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class A
{
    std::function<void()> m_Lambda;

public:
    A(std::function<void()> lambda): m_Lambda(lambda) {}

    void ExecuteLambda()
    {
        m_Lambda();
    }
};

int main()
{
    int i1 = 1;
    int i2 = 2;
    
    const auto lambda = [&]()
    {
        std::cout << "i1 == " << i1 << std::endl;
        std::cout << "i2 == " << i2 << std::endl;
    };

    A a(lambda);
    a.ExecuteLambda();

    return 0;
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/TwQKpR)